# Evaluate $\int\sin(\sin x)~dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

I was skimming the virtual pages here and noticed a limit that made me wonder the following
question: is there any nice way to evaluate the indefinite integral below?

$$\int\sin(\sin x)~dx$$
Perhaps one way might use Taylor expansion. Thanks for any hint, suggestion.

Comment: The Jacobi-Anger expansion gives $\sin(\sin(x))$ in terms of an infinite sine series weighted by Bessel functions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion

Comment: @Bitrex: very interesting. Something new to me. Thank you!

Comment: It looks so simple but it looks difficult also.

Comment: @NancyR: yeah. That's true.

Comment: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117536/evaluate-int-cos-cosx-dx

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401) question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like substitute $u=\sin{x}$ and get

$$\int du \: \frac{\sin{u}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$

You could Taylor expand the denominator and be in a position to integrate even moments of $\sin{u}$ and see if the resulting series is useful.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your suggestion. (+1)

Comment: Do you mean $du$?

Comment: Oops, yes of course

Comment: Out of curiosity if you deifne x to be a number like you would when looking for an answer say  $\frac {3^{1/2}}{2}$ can u just draw it on a triangle then look for the angle on the triangle then use that angle and opp/hyp of that angle to find the side of that triangle then integrate that constant over your bounds?

Comment: @Faust7: not entirely sure what you are asking.  When doing trig substitutions, it is wise to use a right triangle as your guide in relating sines, cosines, etc.  But I do not understand "integrating the constant over the bounds."  $x$ is a variable and is expressed in terms of another variable, $u$.  That's it.

Answer (score 6):

For the maclaurin series of $\sin x$ , $\sin x=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

$\therefore\int\sin(\sin x)~dx=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n\sin^{2n+1}x}{(2n+1)!}dx$

Now for $\int\sin^{2n+1}x~dx$ , where $n$ is any non-negative integer,

$\int\sin^{2n+1}x~dx$

$=-\int\sin^{2n}x~d(\cos x)$

$=-\int(1-\cos^2x)^n~d(\cos x)$

$=-\int\sum\limits_{k=0}^nC_k^n(-1)^k\cos^{2k}x~d(\cos x)$

$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}n!\cos^{2k+1}x}{k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}+C$

$\therefore\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n\sin^{2n+1}x}{(2n+1)!}dx=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k+1}n!\cos^{2k+1}x}{k!(n-k)!(2n+1)!(2k+1)}+C$

Answer (score 1):

Using Euler identity:$e^{xi}=\cos x+i\sin x$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \sin (\sin x) d x 
& =\operatorname{Im} \int e^{i \sin x} d x \\
& =\operatorname{Im} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int \frac{(i \sin x)^n}{n !} d x \\
& =\operatorname{Im} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int \frac{i^{2 n+1} \sin ^{2 n+1} x}{(2 n+1) !} d x \\
& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1) !} \int \sin ^{2 n+1} x d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Putting $u=\cos x$ transforms the integral into
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \int \sin ^{2 n+1} x d x & =-\int\left(1-u^2\right)^n d u =-\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\begin{array}{c}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) \frac{(-1)^k u^{2 k+1}}{2 k+1}
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we can conclude that
$$
\boxed{\int \sin (\sin x) d x  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}  \frac{(-1)^{n+k+1} \cos ^{2 k+1} x}{(2 k+1)(2n+1)!}+C}
$$

Comment: The expression with the sums seems to be more complicated than the original expression.

Comment: Yes, it is not satisfactory.  Any alternative?