# Definite trig integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do I evaluate:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin (\sin x) \ dx$$

I have seen a similar question here but can't find it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287395/evaluate-int-sin-sin-x-mathrmdx

Comment: It [does not appear](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sin%28sin%28x%29%29%20from%200%20to%20pi&t=ff3tb01) that the area under this curve can be expressed with simple functions.  Are you sure the upper bound isn't $2\pi$?

Comment: I'm sure it is $\pi$ but what will happen if we change it to $2\pi$?

Comment: @AlexanderJones If you integrate from $0$ to $2\pi$, you're integrating an odd periodic function over its period--the answer is $0$.  (Which makes the problem a lot easier...)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/287395). This asks for a definite integral, whereas that asks for an indefinite integral. A definite answer to that question would provide an answer to this question, but that question only seems to have suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a closed form (I don't know if one exists in elementary functions), but this series converges pretty fast:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi\sin(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
&=2\int_0^1\frac{\sin(u)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\int_0^1\frac{u^{2k+1}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\int_0^1\frac{v^k}{\sqrt{1-v}}\,\mathrm{d}v\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\frac{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(k+3/2)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\frac{k!\sqrt\pi}{(k+1/2)k!\binom{2k}{k}\frac{\sqrt\pi}{4^k}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\frac{2^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)\binom{2k}{k}}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

When you substitute $u=\sin{x}$, you get

$$2 \int_0^1 du \frac{\sin{u}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$

The integral is related to a [Struve function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/11.5):

$$\mathbf{H}_0(z) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^1 du \frac{\sin{z u}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$

Then the integral is equal to $\pi \mathbf{H}_0(1)$.

See also my solution to [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287395/evaluate-int-sin-sin-x-mathrmdx).

Comment: When I enter my series into Mathematica 8, it recognizes it as `π StruveH[0,1]`

Comment: @robjohn: That is correct and equivalent to what I have written.

Comment: Yeah, I was just noting that Mathematica 8 recognized the function you cited from the series I cited. :-)