# Can we find the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos(\cos x)\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Can we find the integral $$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(\cos x)\,dx\;?$$

Comment: Yes, we can. As far as I remember, the value is related to $J_0(1)$ where appears Bessel $J$ function. Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117536/evaluate-int-cos-cos-x-dx

Comment: could you give me full solution.

Answer (score 3):

For first, consider that:
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^{2n}x\,dx = \frac{2\pi}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\tag{1} $$
hence by exploiting:
$$ \cos z = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n z^{2n}}{(2n)!}, \tag{2}$$
replacing $z$ with $\cos x$ and integrating termwise we get:
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(\cos x)\,dx = 2\pi\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n(n!)^2}=\color{red}{2\pi\, J_0(1)}. \tag{3}$$
Look at [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) for the definition of the Bessel function $J_0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sin(a~\sin x)~dx~=~\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sin(a~\cos x)~dx~=~\frac\pi2~H_0(a)$$

$$\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\cos(a~\cos x)~dx~=~\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\cos(a~\sin x)~dx~=~\frac\pi2~J_0(a)$$

See [Bessel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and [Struve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) function for more [information](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401). Also,

$$\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\cos(a~\tan x)~dx~=~\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\cos(a~\cot x)~dx~=~\frac\pi2~e^{-|a|}$$