# How was the following Integral identity calculated?

Tags: integration, exponential-function, bessel-functions

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\cdot\pi}\left |1+e^{j\cdot k\cdot d\cdot \cos(\theta )}  \right |^{2}d\theta =2(1+ J_{0}\left ( k d \right ))$$
Where:
$$j=\sqrt{-1}$$
and $J_{0}$
is the Bessel function of the first kind of order zero.
k,d are constants.

Comment: Did you mean $(\frac{1}{2\cdot\pi})\cdot \int_{0}^{2\cdot\pi}\left (1+e^{j\cdot k\cdot d\cdot cos(\theta )}  \right )^{2} d\theta$ when writing $(\frac{1}{2\cdot\pi})\cdot \int_{0}^{2\cdot\pi}\left |1+e^{j\cdot k\cdot d\cdot cos(\theta )}  \right |^{2}$?

Comment: Is $j$ the imaginary unit or just a random real variable? What's $J_0$ ?

Comment: j is the imaginary unit indeed and J represents a Bessel function

Comment: OK. I see. Thank you!

Comment: Did you check this question already? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468863/what-is-the-integral-of-e-cos-x

Comment: You're welcome  Noureddine Ouertani

Comment: |x| is the absolute value of x. I used absolute in the equation and not parentheses.

Comment: It's the same because |x|²= x² for all x

Comment: Sorry we are in C .... I think you're right.  You mean $ \sqrt{(re(z))² + (Im(z))²}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea despite the fact that I didn't finish the calculation (yet)... I also don't promise to do so. I hope this helps though somehow ... Maybe you can continue from where I stopped my reasoning.

Let $ I = (\frac{1}{2\cdot\pi})\cdot \int_{0}^{2\cdot\pi}\left (1+e^{j\cdot k\cdot d\cdot cos(\theta )}  \right )^{2}d\theta $

Prove that $ I = 2 (1+ J_{0} ( 2 k d  ))$

Let $x=cos \theta $ which means that $d\theta = \frac{-dx}{sin x}$

Therefore $I = -\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} (1 + e^{jkdx})². \frac{1}{sin x}dx$ : (1)

On the other hand (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function)

$J_0(2kd) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} e^{2jkdsin \alpha}d \alpha = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} cos(-2kdsin(\beta)) d \beta$ :(2)

Now back to (1): $I = -\frac{1}{2 \pi}( \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{sin x} dx + 2 \int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{jkdx}. \frac{1}{sin x}dx + \int_{0}^{2 \pi}e^{2jkdx}. \frac{1}{sin x} dx)$

Can you continue from here? Or did you do this kind of reasoning already?

Comment: I found a mistake in this equation, on the right side and corrected it. I corrected the question and I managed to find the answer. the equation was taken from an article. I will post the full answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.\begin{align}
\left|1+e^{j\cdot k\cdot d\cdot \cos(\theta )}  \right|^{2}&=
\big(1+e^{j\cdot k\cdot d\cdot \cos(\theta )}\big)
\big(1+e^{-j\cdot k\cdot d\cdot \cos(\theta )}\big)
\\
&=  e^{-j\cdot k\cdot d\cdot \cos(\theta )} + 2 + e^{j\cdot k\cdot d\cdot \cos(\theta )}
\end{align}
$$=2+2\cdot \cos(k\cdot d\cdot \cos(\theta))=2\cdot(1+\cos(k\cdot d\cdot \cos(\theta))$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\cdot\pi}|1+e^{j\cdot k\cdot d\cdot \cos(\theta )}|^{2}d\theta =
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\cdot\pi}(1+e^{j\cdot k\cdot d\cdot \cos(\theta )})(1+e^{-j\cdot k\cdot d\cdot \cos(\theta )})d\theta $$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\cdot\pi}(2(1+cos(cos(k\cdot d\cdot cos(\theta)))d\theta 
$$
Using the following identity:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\cdot\pi}cos(a\cdot cos(\theta)d\theta =J_{0}(a)$$
We get:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\cdot\pi}(2(1+cos(cos(k\cdot d\cdot cos(\theta)))d\theta=2(1+J_{0}(k\cdot d))$$