# Is there a nice expansion for $\int e^{\cos(x)}dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

This indefinite integral has no closed form $$I(x)=\int_0^xe^{\cos(t)}dt$$
The usual expansions of $ I (x) $ are generally obtained by expanding $ e ^ x $ and integrating $ \int \cos ^ \alpha (x) dx $, thus obtaining a series in terms of the hypergeometric function. Since I am not very familiar with the hypergeometric function, and its properties are not very well known, I was wondering if there was an expansion for $ I (x) $ in terms of "more known" functions.

This is my attempt:

Applying the [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) for the composite function $f(x)=\exp(\cos(x))$ we can show that $f^{(2n+1)}(0)=0$ and $f^{(2n)}(0)$ are the number of partitions of a $2n$-set into even blocks [A005046](https://oeis.org/A005046) therefore we can express $f (x)$ with the following taylor series:

$$\frac{e^{\cos(x)}}{e}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\sum_{h=0}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^h(h-k)^{2n}}{2^{k-1}k!}\binom{2k}{h} \Bigg)\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

> $$\frac{1}{e}\int_0^xe^{\cos(t)}dt=x+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\sum_{h=0}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^h(h-k)^{2n}}{2^{k-1}k!(2n+1)!}\binom{2k}{h} \Bigg)\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n)!}$$

[image]

Comment: It looks a little $I_0$, the bessel function but I'm not sure whether it will help...

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3371727/870871

Comment: In the alleged duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2468863/442 two of the answers are series expansions.