# How can I solve this integral $\int_{-1}^1 \int_0^{π}\sin(x)e^{\cos y} \,dy\,dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have trouble solving this integral

$$\int_{-1}^1 \int_0^{π} \sin(x)e^{\cos y} \,dy\,dx$$

Any advice on this would be really helpful.

Comment: Formatting tip: your posts will look nicer and be easier to read if you use `\sin`, `\cos` and so on for standard functions.

Comment: Hint: It splits into a product of two separate integrals for $x$ and $y$. One of these is so easy that you don't even need to do the other (quite hard) one.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are just having trouble with the first integral

$$\int_0^{\pi}e^{\cos(y)}dy$$

See question :[What is the integral of $e^{\cos x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468863/what-is-the-integral-of-e-cos-x)

But quite simply, since the outer integral is $\int_{-1}^1\sin(x)dx$ which is an odd function therefore the integral is $0$