# $\int e^{\sin(x)-x}dx$ = special function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

The following integral has no simple solution in terms of elementary functions $$\int_a^b e^{\sin(x)-x}dx$$

See [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int+exp%28sin%28x%29-x%29dx):

> *no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions*.

*Question:* Can this integral be expressed as a known special function?

Comment: Almost surely the integrand does not have a closed-form antiderivative in terms of elementary functions. Where did this integral arise?

Comment: Is there an application in mind?  It’s far more likely to have been studied if it is useful for something.

Comment: Technically, there is a [Kampe de Feriet function](https://functions.wolfram.com/Notations/5/06/imagetext/0043/text43.gif) in [Wolfram functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/Notations/5/), but not implemented in Mathematica. The integrand equals $$e^{-x}(\cosh(\sin(x))+\sinh(\sin(x)))$$ and $\int \sin(\sin(x))dx$ is expressible in terms of this function, so maybe yours is too.

Comment: For the simpler problem $\int e^{\cos x} dx$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2468961/442

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, except the very special function @Tyma Gaidash mentioned in comments, there is no closed form.

However, doing the same as @Laplacian in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468863/what-is-the-integral-of-e-cos-x/2468961#2468961), we can write
$$\int e^{\sin(x)-x}\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{n!} \int e^{-x} \sin ^n(x)\,dx$$
$$I_n=\int e^{-x} \sin ^n(x)\,dx$$ $$I_n=\frac{e^{-x} \left(e^{2 i x}-1\right)  \sin ^n(x)}{1+i n}\,\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{2+n+i}{2}
   ;\frac{2-n+i}{2} ;e^{2 i x}\right)$$ where appears the Gaussian hypergeometric function.

This could look impressive but the expressions are quite simple. They all write
$$I_n=-\frac {e^{-x}} {a_n} J_n$$ where the first $a_n$ are
$$\{1,2,10,40,680,416,20128,41600,5233280\cdots\}$$ which is not a known sequence.

The first $J_n$ are

The first integrals are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & J_n \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & \cos (x)+\sin (x) \\
 2 & -\cos (2 x)+2 \sin (2 x)+5 \\
 3 & 15 \cos (x)-3 \cos (3 x)+15 \sin (x)-\sin (3 x) \\
 4 & -68 \cos (2 x)+5 \cos (4 x)+136 \sin (2 x)-20 \sin (4 x)+255 \\
 5 & 130 \cos (x)-39 \cos (3 x)+5 \cos (5 x)+130 \sin (x)-13 \sin (3 x)+\sin (5 x)  
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using only the terms in the table
$$\sum_{n=0}^5 \frac 1{n!} \int_0^\pi e^{-x} \sin ^n(x)\,dx=\frac{15591}{8840}-\frac{5833 e^{-\pi }}{8840}=1.73517$$ while numerical integration leads to $1.73552$. Adding the two next terms would give  $1.73552$.

Comment: $\,_2\text F_1(1,a;b;z)$ [is an incomplete beta function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/03/0006/), so you can simplify the coefficients

Comment: @TymaGaidash. Thanks but I did not want to do it because of the complex arguments. But (once more) you are totally right. Cheers :-)